# how can i test javascript in my app from the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My consumer subscriptions to channels aren't being created How can I debug from the console?

I tried:

```
    consumer.subscriptions.create(channel: "RoomChannel", {
    connected() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
    console.log('Live')
    alert("It works!")
    },
```

I expected to get a "listening" message in development log

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Action Cable logging, you need to add to config/environments/development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_cable.log = true
end
```

Comment: Wrong ... Do you know the right syntax for rails 7.1 ?